# Integer NEQ Int(Integer) Craziness

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to detect whether I've multiplied the numerator and denominator of a complex fraction enough times (by 10/10) to get integers on both top and bottom. Often my algorithm works. Sometimes, though, the `Int()` function doesn't work as expected and I get huge numbers out of it. Here is a simplified version of what I'm running:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset RealNumber = RandRange(1000, 10000) / 1000 />
    RealNumber = "#RealNumber#" Int(RealNumber) = "#Int(RealNumber)#"<br />
    <cfloop condition="RealNumber NEQ Int(RealNumber)">
        <cfset RealNumber = RealNumber * 10 />
        RealNumber = "#RealNumber#" Int(RealNumber) = "#Int(RealNumber)#"<br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Most of the time this gets what I want, but sometimes it looks like this:

```
RealNumber = "9.184" Int(RealNumber) = "9"
RealNumber = "91.84" Int(RealNumber) = "91"
RealNumber = "918.4" Int(RealNumber) = "918"
RealNumber = "9184" Int(RealNumber) = "9183"
RealNumber = "91840" Int(RealNumber) = "91839"
RealNumber = "918400" Int(RealNumber) = "918399"
RealNumber = "9184000" Int(RealNumber) = "9183999"
RealNumber = "91840000" Int(RealNumber) = "91839999"
RealNumber = "918400000" Int(RealNumber) = "918399999"
RealNumber = "9184000000" Int(RealNumber) = "9183999999"
RealNumber = "91840000000" Int(RealNumber) = "91839999999"
RealNumber = "918400000000" Int(RealNumber) = "918399999999"
RealNumber = "9.184E+012" Int(RealNumber) = "9.184E+012"
RealNumber = "9.184E+013" Int(RealNumber) = "9.184E+013"
RealNumber = "9.184E+014" Int(RealNumber) = "9.184E+014"
RealNumber = "9.184E+015" Int(RealNumber) = "9.184E+015"
```

Or even like this:

```
RealNumber = "2.152" Int(RealNumber) = "2"
RealNumber = "21.52" Int(RealNumber) = "21"
RealNumber = "215.2" Int(RealNumber) = "215"
RealNumber = "2152" Int(RealNumber) = "2152"
RealNumber = "21520" Int(RealNumber) = "21520"
RealNumber = "215200" Int(RealNumber) = "215200"
RealNumber = "2152000" Int(RealNumber) = "2152000"
RealNumber = "21520000" Int(RealNumber) = "21520000"
RealNumber = "215200000" Int(RealNumber) = "215200000"
RealNumber = "2152000000" Int(RealNumber) = "2152000000"
RealNumber = "21520000000" Int(RealNumber) = "21520000000"
RealNumber = "215200000000" Int(RealNumber) = "215200000000"
RealNumber = "2.152E+012" Int(RealNumber) = "2.152E+012"
RealNumber = "2.152E+013" Int(RealNumber) = "2.152E+013"
RealNumber = "2.152E+014" Int(RealNumber) = "2.152E+014"
RealNumber = "2.152E+015" Int(RealNumber) = "2.152E+015"
RealNumber = "2.152E+016" Int(RealNumber) = "2.152E+016"
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I compensate for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Val() seems to correct it too:

```
<cfoutput>

    <cfset RealNumber = RandRange(1000, 10000) / 1000 />
    "#val(RealNumber)#" = INT: "#val(Int(RealNumber))#"<br />
    <cfloop condition="val(RealNumber) NEQ Val(Int(RealNumber))">
        <cfset RealNumber = RealNumber * 10 />
        "#val(RealNumber)#" INT: "#val(Int(RealNumber))#"<br />
    </cfloop>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: `<cfloop condition="Val(RealNumber) NEQ Val(Int(RealNumber))">` solves the problem and gets the least amount of loop time.

Comment: @Dave - I am a little skeptical about that ;) PrecisionEvaluate usually results in far fewer iterations because it is not using approximate numbers like 9.183999999. So evaluating 9.184 requires four (4) iterations instead of ~thirteen (13) with `val`. That said, it is not a significant difference overall, unless you are handling hundreds or thousands of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> RealNumber = "9.184E+015"

The output is deceptive. If you use `#RealNumber.toString()#` the real value is probably something like `9.183999999999998E15`. CF uses the approximate type [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) for most mathematical operations. So what you are seeing is normal behavior for [floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002821/why-does-this-subtraction-not-equal-zero). If you need greater accuracy, use [PrecisionEvaluate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd9.html). It makes use of [BigDecimals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for arithmetic operations (because they are more precise than java.lang.Double).

Comment: `<cfloop condition="RealNumber NEQ PrecisionEvaluate(Int(RealNumber))">` still gets the huge numbers.

Comment: That is because you have to use it on both values ie `precisionEvaluate(RealNumber * 10)`. Otherwise CF falls back to using floating point numbers when you perform math operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javacast.. ColdFusion is trying to dynamically determine your variable type and is not doing a great job.. Javacast covers a multitude of sins.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset RealNumber = RandRange(1000, 10000) / 1000 />
RealNumber = "#RealNumber#" Int(RealNumber) = "#Int(RealNumber)#"<br />
<cfloop condition="RealNumber NEQ Int(RealNumber)">
    <cfset RealNumber = RealNumber * 10 />
    RealNumber = "#RealNumber#" Int(RealNumber) = "#javaCast("int", RealNumber)#"<br />
</cfloop>
```

Comment: This: `<cfloop condition="RealNumber NEQ JavaCast('int', RealNumber)">` still gets the huge numbers.