# Arithmetic Error

Tags: coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this subtraction not equal zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002821/why-does-this-subtraction-not-equal-zero)

I just came across a weird situation. Why is below code not returning 0? Instead it's returning a very small negative number.

```
<cfset x = 5448.10-3311.23-2136.87>
<cfoutput>x=#x#</cfoutput>
```

Above code will output: x=4.54747350886E-013

I ran above code both in CF9 and CF10 with the same results.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it use double precision?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: @RiverC - +1. As you suspected, yes. If you are not familiar with CF it is mostly typeless, but is built atop java. When math operators are used, numeric values are implicitly converted to `java.lang.Double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfset x = PrecisionEvaluate(5448.10-3311.23-2136.87)>
<cfoutput>x=#x#</cfoutput>
```

Doc for `PrecisionEvaluate()`:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd9.html

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated it is Floating point accuracy related. I just wanted to point out a resolution if you are trying to get a reasonable result

```
<cfset x1 = 5448.19-3311.23-2136.87 />
<cfset x2 = numberformat(x1, "9.99") />
<cfoutput>x1=#x1#<br />x2=#x2#</cfoutput>
```

Result

```
x1=0.0899999999997
x2=0.09
```

The numberformat function will round the number to the specified decimal place when given mask.