# strange behavior with Coldfusion loops?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Today I have written small program in ColdFusion to find the square root of a number. I found a strange issue. Not sure am I doing any silly mistake ?

```
<cfscript>
num = 16;
n = 0.0001;
i = 0;
for (i=0;i<num;i=i+n)
{
    if((i*i)>num){
        i = i - n;
        break;
    }
}
writedump(i);
</cfscript>
```

The output is 3.999 instead of 4 when num = 16. Where as when I set it to 36 its output is 6.
Not sure why I am getting 3.999 where as it should be 4.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I altered your code to output the conditions you are seeing like so:

```
<cfscript>
num = 16.00;
n = 0.0001;
i = 0;
for (i=0;i<num;i=i+n)
{
     writeoutput(i & " i * i = " & (i*i));
     writeoutput('<br>');
    if((i*i)>num){
        i = i - n;
        break;
    }
}
writedump(i);
 writeoutput('<br>');
</cfscript>
```

This outputs all the numbers and the multiples - a long list. The last 3 lines look like this:

```
3.9999 i * i = 15.99920001
4 i * i = 16
3.9999
```

That seems like expected behavior to me. Inside your break code you are reducing the value of i with this line:

```
i = i - n;
```

Is that not what you want?

Comment: Not quite :) If the final value really was `i=4`, then the `if` condition ie `(4*4) > 16` would not equate to true. As [@Sonu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27042387/104223) pointed out, the behavior is due to [floating point math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002821/why-does-this-subtraction-not-equal-zero). The value of `i` is actually slightly greater than 4 and that is why the `if` condition is executing earlier than he expected.

Comment: Got it! I missed that ... read it as "less than". in keeping with the for loop. So yeah, gotta be floating point.

Comment: Darn it. Wish there was not a five minute limit on comment edits! I was trying to add a clarification for the OP to the effect of "Mark already knows this, but based on your code you are probably expecting x instead of y" but got distracted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the if condition. When you use `num=36` in that case at `6.001` the if condition gets evaluated and you get `6`. But in the case of `num=16` the if condition gets evaluated at `4.00` and you get `3.999`. 
But you may ask why at `4.00` it gets evaluated due to [floating  point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and floating point arithmetic.  
 
**Edit:**
You can use [Newton method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to find square root of any +ve number.By this method you can achieve better performance over for loop that you had used.

Comment: No maybe about :) It is definitely due to floating point math. +1

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do all the heavy lifting when we can use power of java as below:

```
<cfset testNumber = 20.50 />
<cfset mathObj = createObject( "java", "java.lang.Math" ) />
<cfset sqrtNumber = mathObj.sqrt(testNumber) />
<cfdump var="#sqrtNumber#"><cfabort>
```

Output:

```
4 -> 2
6 -> 2.44948974278
36- > 6
20.50 - > 4.52769256907
```

As you can see it works on all values including decimals. I hope this helps.
Note: Before passing values to the **mathObj.sqrt**, you should first check for negative values. You can not have sqrt of negative numbers.

**Edit**:
As Leigh pointed out there is [already a function](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Sqr) in CF, you can use that as follows:

```
<cfset testNumber = 36 />
<cfset sqrtNumber = sqr(testNumber) />
```

You will get output same as Java version code, only difference is that when you pass negative value in java code, you will get a gibberish value. With CF, you will get an error like this **The 1 parameter of the Sqr function, which is now -122.0, must be a non-negative real number**.

Comment: Not all CF developers know java.

Comment: @DanBracuk, True. I think if CF developers know a little bit of java then it will help them immensely as CF uses Java under the hood. But that's my opinion.

Comment: I thought it was a learning exercise :) @Tushar - Java is certainly helpful (when needed). In this case there is already a [CF function](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Sqr) for that.

Comment: @Leigh, Ouch, totally forgot about that. Thanks for reminding that one. I don't know why i went straight to Java instead of looking in to CF.

Comment: No worries. There are so many functions now, it is easy to forget a few. Still good to learn about the java options too. Though as I always say "read the java API carefully" ;-) As a strongly typed language, there are some nuances that differ from CF. Things that can bite you if you not aware of them :)