# number formatting with truncate

Tags: coldfusion

I need to format some numbers without rounding them and also add two 0s if they are integers as follows.

given : 10.20 , result : 10.20
given : 10.56556,  result : 10.56
given : 65000 , result : 65000.00

This is what I have so far:

```
<cfscript>
vars = {};
vars.rate = 10.20;     // should yield to : 10.20
//vars.base_salary = 10.56556; // should yield to : 10.56
//vars.base_salary = 65000;    // should yield to : 65000.00



vars.formatted1 = trim(numberFormat((vars.rate * 100) / 100, "__________.__"));
vars.formatted2 = trim(numberFormat(int(vars.rate * 100) / 100, "__________.__"));

vars.formatted3 = NumberFormat((ceiling(vars.rate*100)/100), '9.99');

writeDump(vars);
</cfscript>
```

Notice, formatted2 for 10.20 yields to 10.19, which is not correct. 
any help?

Comment: (Edit) A) Since it looks like you are representing currency, why are you using [floating point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002821/why-does-this-subtraction-not-equal-zero)? When precision is important, never use "approximate" types. Instead use BigDecimal, `PrecisionEvaluate()`, etcetera. B) While possible, why round down? That is a bit atypical for currency.

Comment: @Leigh, a) they are currency indeed. The application code that I have inherited is creating decimals, which is a long story. b) The "management" decision was not to round them up, but just cut them 2nd digit after the decimal. Again, I have had no say in that.  Interesting thing is that this only fails for 10.20, and works fine for say 9.20 ,11.20 or any other number i tested so far : trim(numberFormat(int(vars.rate * 100) / 100, "__________.__"))

Comment: *this only fails for 10.20, and works fine for say*  That is because CF uses an approximate type, ie double. So it will always happen with certain numbers because *...[certain] decimal numbers that "look" round in base 10, are not exactly representable in base 2*. For example if you multiply `10.20 * 100`, you would expect to see "1020". Due to the use of approximate types, what you actually get is something like `1019.999999...` http://trycf.com/gist/90a8b072eb63e87a7b54975f3b075e37/acf2016?theme=monokai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you are representing currency, do not use [floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002821/why-does-this-subtraction-not-equal-zero). CF typically uses [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) to represent numbers (and when formatting with NumberFormat) which is an approximate type. Do not use approximate types when precision is important, like with currency. Instead use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and functions like [PrecisionEvaluate()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/precisionevaluate.html).

Without more details, I would ask why truncate the numbers? Though possible, it is a bit atypical for currency. At least for U.S. currency which is usually rounded using [HALF_EVEN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN):

> .. round[s] towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even
>   neighbor....

That said, to answer the question you can truncate the numbers by creating a BigDecimal. Then using setScale() to specify the desired number of decimal places and override the default rounding mode.

**NB:** Be sure to read the docs on [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) so you fully understand how it handles various values

**Example:**

```
doubleValue = 10.56556;
mode = createObject("java", "java.math.RoundingMode");
decimalValue = javacast("bigdecimal", doubleValue).setScale(2, mode.DOWN);
writeOutput("decimalValue = "& decimalValue);
```

**Results:**

```
decimalValue = 10.20
decimalValue = 10.56
decimalValue = 6500.00
```

Comment: super impressive!